# Video in modal only audio and spinning wheel

Tags: modal-dialog, html5-video

I'm trying to change a template from html5up to display video instead of an image in a modal. The video plays but I don't see it, only audio.
The code is here https://html5up.net/ethereal (thanks to html5up.net ! )[image: Screenshot]

I tried to exchange

```
<a href="images/gallery/fulls/02.jpg" class="image filtered span-1-5" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/02.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

simply with

```
<a href="movies/myMovie.mp4" class="image filtered span-1-5" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/02.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

The result is what you see in the screenshot. Next I tried using bootstrap lib, next I tried with an iframe:

```
<div class="modal" id="modal">
 <div class="modal-video">
  <iframe id="video" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
...
 <script>
    function showModal(videoUrl) {
      const modal = document.getElementById('modal');
      const video = document.getElementById('video');
      video.src = videoUrl;
      modal.classList.add('show');
...
```

No display. :-(
Any hint to what is preventing the video to show is gratefully received.
(The videos are all h264.)